# is facebook webhook available for ads (marketing api) data?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api, facebook-webhooks

Am using facebook marketing api to monitor ads insights on campaigns and i want to be notified on the updates of the statistics on my campaigns but i can't find how to use webhook with the marketing api data :  campaigns, adsets and ads  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api.

Comment: You want FB to repeat every ad view as a request to your service? What? Do you imagine the amount of requests?

Comment: No  i just want to be notified when a new campaign/adset or ad is created, for the statistics i use cron jobs.

Comment: All entities are (can't find it in docs but it works in such way) sorted by updated_time so the most recent are on top. In that way you can just repeat the query stopping listing JSON-reponse pages when the last entity is old and known.

Comment: @Nakilon the entities are sorted by default or i should mention that in the request ??

Comment: It is by default.

Comment: Have a look at [**ricks**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52938866/3679900) which points to [Ad Rules Engine](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/ad-rules)